# Is a proof by recurrence a good start for this problem or am I going the wrong direction?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

f: $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a t-periodic function. Show that $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$,$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x + nt) = f(x)$

I was thinking that doing a recursive argument for $n>=0$ and $n<0$ was the way to go but I'm stuck now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prove it for all $n\geq 0$ by induction, then you use the fact that $f\big((x+2nt) -nt \big) = f(x + nt) = f(x +2nt)$ is true for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\geq 0$, so if you replace $x+2nt$ by $X$ you get $f(X-nt) = f(X)$ for all $X\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\geq 0$.